# Send additional information with Raven.send_event

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sentry, raven

I have integrated Sentry in my `Ruby On Rails` application and I want to send a custom event when a specific case happens, I am able to send the events with

```
Raven.send_event({:message => 'Custom event'})
```

How do i send additional information related to the same. I need to send for example, `user_id`, `email_id`, `login_name` and other custom parameters.

Comment: you can use`Raven.user_context email: 'example@mail.com'`

Comment: I need to send specific custom information everytime, so do you suggest that i should set `user_context ` everytime before calling `send_event`?

Comment: you write a method to set context in application controller and call it in before action

Answer (score 2):

You can set user_context to raven using `Raven.user_context` method

You can write a method to set context in Application Controller and call the same in before action

For example

```
Raven.user_context(
# a unique ID which represents this user
id: current_user.id, # 1

# the actor's email address, if available
 email: current_user.email, # "example@example.org"

 # the actor's username, if available
  username: current_user.username, # "foo"

  # the actor's IP address, if available
  ip_address: request.ip # '127.0.0.1'
)
```

You can write in application controller as

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
before_action :set_raven_context, if: proc { Rails.env.production? } //If you want to set only in prod

def set_raven_context


Raven.user_context(
# a unique ID which represents this user
id: current_user.id, # 1

# the actor's email address, if available
 email: current_user.email, # "example@example.org"

 # the actor's username, if available
  username: current_user.username, # "foo"

  # the actor's IP address, if available
  ip_address: request.ip # '127.0.0.1'
)

#You can also set extra context using `Raven.extra_context`
Raven.extra_context app: url, environment: Rails.env, time: Time.now
end

end
```

Comment: Hi @Sumanth Madishetty, thanks for your answer, not sure i can use an application controller here as the information i need to send changes every time and I am doing this in a background worker.

Comment: i just used application controller as i thought you would need to set context every time, if you want to do that in explicit methods you can do that too

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @opensource-developer answer:
You can find more available extra parameters here => [Sentry Usage Page](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/ruby/usage/#optional-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing similar issue, i managed to do it via, under the key `extra` you can specify any extra keys which you want to send to sentry for further debugging

```
    Raven.capture_message "custom message",
      logger: 'logger',
      extra: {
        time_at: Time.now
      },
      tags: {
        env: Rails.env
      }
```